# Close marker in the Line Charts

Tags: swift, charts, xib

[image: screenshot]

I create a custom Marker with xib, but when I try to close the marker it display a new marker with the new position, I need to close the marker when the image is clicked, I try with a button and with TapGestureRecognizer and still I got no action from that, thanks an advance.

**Charts version: 3.4.0
**Xcode version: 11.3.1
**Swift version: 5

public class WeekMarkerView: MarkerView {

```
@IBOutlet weak var bgView: ShadowView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var amountCurrencyLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var closeImage: UIImageView!

public override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 4

    self.offset.x = -self.frame.size.width / 2.0
    self.offset.y = -self.frame.size.height - 7.0

    let touchTest = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapClose(sender:)))
    closeImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    closeImage.addGestureRecognizer(touchTest)
}

@objc func tapClose(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("************************")
    print("Close is ok!!!!!!")
    print("************************")
}

public override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    let day = Int(entry.x)
    dateLbl.text = String.init(format: "\(SpendingsVC.instance.days[day])", Int(round(entry.x)))
    amountCurrencyLbl.text = String.init(format: "%d KWD", Int(round(entry.y)))
    layoutIfNeeded()
}}
```

Comment: Could you add a little more context to your question?  It is not evident from the question title what language you are coding, what's the platform, etc.

Comment: **Charts : 3.4.0
**Xcode : 11.3.1
**Swift : 5

Comment: That information should go into the original post, not the comments